# Fetching data and sums according to date in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sum, greenplum

I am working in Greenplum - postgresql DB and have below structure of data:

[image]

In this I need below logic to implement (some of which I already implemented):

```
CASE WHEN PDATE IS NOT NULL THEN to_char(PDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
WHEN PDATE IS NULL THEN to_char(NDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD N')
WHEN NDATEIS NULL THEN 'NO PO' ELSE 'NO PO' END
```

According to which I need QTY and VName.

> QTY: Sum(Qty) according to min (PDATE and NDATE)
>
> VName: VName according to min (PDATE and NDATE)

DESIRED OUTPUT:

[image: DESIRED OUTPUT]

as far I have made below query:

```
SELECT
    ITEM ,
    MIN(CASE WHEN PDATE IS NOT NULL THEN to_char(PDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
             WHEN PDATE IS NULL THEN to_char(NDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD N')
             WHEN NDATE IS NULL THEN 'NO PO' ELSE 'NO PO' END) AS PRO
FROM
    Table
GROUP BY
    ITEM
```

Please help me out with the query

Comment: I think to be safe you better show us your exact desired output.

Comment: Desired Output is shown as screenshot

Comment: I'm going to answer this, but you should know you asked a really confusing question.

Comment: Ya I know its quite confusing, but if you can share you confusion I can clear it!!

Comment: What version of Postgres are you using?

Comment: This is a very old version. You might want to consider switching to a new one. Such queries are much easier to write with a more complete set of SQL features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anshul, your solution works but it will come with a performance hit as you are joining to your table twice which forces the database to scan your table twice.  The better solution is to use an analytical function and only reference the table once.

Here is an example:

```
    CREATE TABLE anshul
    (
      item character varying,
      pdate date,
      ndate date,
      qty integer,
      vname character varying
    )
    WITH (APPENDONLY=true)
    DISTRIBUTED BY (item);

    INSERT INTO ANSHUL VALUES 
    ('ABC', NULL, '2015-12-31', 10, 'Y JACK SOLLEN'),
    ('HRD', '2016-01-29', '2016-1-8', 5, 'H HARRIS'),
    ('HRD', '2015-09-07', '2015-10-09', 31, 'G JOE'),
    ('HRD', '2015-09-30', '2015-09-07', 28, 'K KAMATH'),
    ('GGT', '2015-12-10', '2015-12-12', 10, 'P QUIK'),
    ('GGT', '2015-12-27', NULL, 20, NULL),
    ('GGT', '2015-12-10', '2016-01-04', 22, 'U RITZ'),
    ('GGT', '2016-01-07', '2016-01-07', 22, 'S SUE DAL'),
    ('OWE', NULL, '2015-12-22', 6, 'J JASON NIT'),
    ('OWE', NULL, '2015-11-05', 2, 'P QUEER'),
    ('OWE', NULL, '2015-11-05', 5, 'K KITTAN');
```

And here is the query which borrows some of the code you already had figured out.

```
    SELECT item,
            sum(qty) AS qty,
            array_to_string(array_agg(vname), ',') AS vname
    FROM    (
            SELECT  item, 
                    rank() OVER(PARTITION BY item ORDER BY desired_date) AS rank,
                    qty,
                    vname
            FROM    (SELECT item,
                            qty,
                            vname,
                            CASE WHEN PDATE IS NOT NULL THEN pdate
                            WHEN PDATE IS NULL THEN ndate END AS desired_date
                    FROM anshul
                    ) AS sub1
            ) AS sub
    WHERE sub.rank = 1
    GROUP BY item
    ORDER BY item;
```

And the results:

```
     item | qty |      vname       
    ------+-----+------------------
     ABC  |  10 | Y JACK SOLLEN
     GGT  |  32 | P QUIK,U RITZ
     HRD  |  31 | G JOE
     OWE  |   7 | K KITTAN,P QUEER
```

Comment: Thank You very much Jon.. I appreciate your help.. and undoubtedly your solution is much efficient than mine.. 
Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Tim for your help.. It took me some time to create the query, but in the end its completed.. To save the time I posted the question in forum, which ended the same to me - It took time..

Well here's the query

```
SELECT
    FO.ID ,
    (CASE WHEN FO.DateQ IS NOT NULL THEN to_char(FO.DateQ ,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
          WHEN FO.DateQ IS NULL THEN to_char(FO.Datew ,'YYYY-MM-DD N') 
          WHEN FO.Datew IS NULL AND FO.DateQ IS NULL THEN 'NO PO' END) AS DATER ,
    FO.QTY ,
    FO.VNAME
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            NT.ID ,
            PT.DATEQ ,
            PT.DATEW ,
            SUM(NT.QTY) AS QTY ,
            array_to_string(array_agg(NT.VNAME) ,', ') AS VNAME
        FROM
            TABLENAME NT INNER JOIN(
                SELECT
                    AST.ID ,
                    AST.DateQ ,
                    (CASE WHEN AST.DateQ IS NULL THEN AST.DateW ELSE NULL END) AS DateW
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            ID ,
                            MIN(PDATE) AS DATEQ ,
                            MIN(CASE WHEN pdate IS NULL THEN ndate END) DATEW
                        FROM
                            TABLENAME
                        GROUP BY
                            ID
                    ) AST
            ) PT
                ON NT.ID = PT.ID
            AND NT.PDATE = PT.DATEQ
            OR NT.NDATE = PT.DATEW
        GROUP BY
            NT.ID ,
            PT.DATEQ ,
            PT.DATEW
    ) FO
ORDER BY
    FO.ID
```

Consider ID as Item.

Comment: This is not that intuitive to me, but I'm glad I could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer assumes you are using Postgres version 8.4 or later, which ships with an aggregate function called `ARRAY_AGG()`.  I use `ARRAY_AGG()` to create comma-separated lists for the `VNAME` for each `ITEM`-`MIN(DATE)` group.

```
SELECT t1.ITEM, t1.DATE, t1.QTY, t1.VNAME
FROM
(
    SELECT t.ITEM, t.DATE AS DATE, SUM(t.QTY) AS QTY, ARRAY_AGG(VNAME) AS VNAME
    FROM
    (
        SELECT t.ITEM, LEAST(t.PDATE, t.NDATE) AS DATE, t.QTY, t.VNAME
        FROM Table t
    ) t
    GROUP BY t.ITEM, t.DATE
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t.ITEM, MIN(LEAST(t.PDATE, t.NDATE)) AS DATE
    FROM Table t
    GROUP BY t.ITEM
) t2
ON t1.ITEM = t2.ITEM AND t1.PDATE = t2.PDATE
```

**Explanation:**

The first query obtains the `QTY` sums and `VNAME` CSV aggregates for each `ITEM`-`PDATE` combination.  However, you only want the aggregates from the *earliest* date in each of these groups.  The second query, to which the first query is joined, filters off the unwanted groups, leaving you with the result you want.

Since you are using Postgres 8.2, you will have to define your own custom function:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE ARRAY_AGG (anyelement)
(
    sfunc = array_append,
    stype = anyarray,
    initcond = '{}'
);
```

Comment: Hi Tim,

ARRAY_AGG  is working fine with the query, and sum of qty is also working but the case condition for PDATE and NDATE is not there.. where should I add that case in this query?

Comment: Why does your `CASE` statement have logic for the `NDATE` column since this doesn't even appear in your results?

Comment: It appear in my result for Item ABC and OWE, as PDATE for both of them are null, so it should pick NDATE Minimum value...

Comment: I slightly modified the query to use the `LEAST()` function, to take the smaller of the `PDATE` and `NDATE`.  If either value be `NULL` it will be ignored, so if both are `NULL` then some other row will appear in the result set.

Comment: Can you give my updated query a try and let me know what you get?

Comment: Hello are you still there?

Comment: Its same which you posted above..:

SELECT t1.ITEM, t1.DATE, t1.QTY, t1.VNAME
FROM
(
    SELECT t.ITEM, t.PDATE AS DATE, SUM(t.QTY) AS QTY, ARRAY_AGG(VNAME) AS VNAME
    FROM racesbi_edw.Missing_Parts_Test t
    GROUP BY t.ITEM, t.PDATE
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t.ITEM, MIN(t.PDATE) AS DATE
    FROM racesbi_edw.Missing_Parts_Test t
    GROUP BY t.ITEM
) t2
ON t1.ITEM= t2.ITEM AND t1.DATE = t2.DATE

Comment: No, I wrapped the `LEAST()` function in `MIN()` in the second inner query.  Try again

Comment: Its giving the same result as before.. ABC and OWE Items are ignored in final outcome..

Comment: This should not be happening.  My approach is correct.  Your best bet now is to test the various pieces of the query until you get it working.

Comment: No issues, I was just saying what I got.. If you don't want to go more its totally your wish, no one is forcing you to solve this.. I was having trouble with logic implementation so I asked.. Anyways thanks for your help.. Have a good day..

Comment: I'm back.  I need to debug the query in real life not on SO.  Can you create a Fiddle for this query?